# html box with arrow inside

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

A client is requesting boxes on his website that should appear like the one below

[image: box appearance]

as you can see, the box has a small arrow with a unique shape on the left hand side.

I have tried everything and visited lots of links and i can't design it.

the problem is, this box will have different sizes and that image should always be in the center of the box and should hide a portion of the border (as u can see)

please help, i am all out of options here.

Thank you,
Yasser

Comment: used to css3 :after, :before and rotate .....

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/

Comment: If you look further down the page you'll notice an effect similar the one you need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here I made fiddle for you:

```
<div class="box"></div>

.box{
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.box:before{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    border:10px solid black;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent black;
    top:40px;
}
.box:after{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    border:9px solid white;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent white;
    top:41px;
    left:-1px;
}
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/y5dZj/

As others told `:after` and `:before` used

-edited: Dont use transform if you want full compatibility in old browsers. My example will work even in IE8(not sure about 7)

Comment: @VytautasButkus Great answer, could you explain how this works?

Comment: well you create simple box, after that you need some pseudo element which looks like arrow, because you need only outline of that arrow you need two elements. So one pseudo element makes black arrow and another pseudo element makes white arrow on top.
To get arrow look you can experiment with border properties or read here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: this is very nice and it's working on IE8. However, is there a way to control the size of the triangle ? it's too big. Also, if i changed the height of the box, the arrow will not move to the middle :(

Comment: sizing for arrow is adjusted by change'ing border width property. Also if you want to move arrow up or down you need to adjust top property. These things applies to both :before and :after element, because arrow is composition of "two arrows"
Also if you think that I answered your question you may tick it as correct answer :)

Comment: just one more question please :) ..only one :) .. how to change the border color? when i try to make it grey, the arrow is still black, so i tried to change border color of the arrows, sometimes i get square shape .. sometimes only white arrow without borders .. this is the last tip :)

Comment: Ok, forget about that last question :) .. it was my bad.. i forgot to add the "#" before the color code :) .. you're the man, you saved the project :)

Answer (score 2):

Used to this

**Css**

```
 div{
    position:relative;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background:red;
    }
    div:after{
    content:'';
      position:absolute;
      left:-10px;
      top:50%;
      margin-top:-10px;
      width:20px;
      height:20px;
      background:#fff;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ZJtn8V3V)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/vKY3x/

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus varius felis, sit amet malesuada urna euismod convallis. Donec at diam eros
</div>

div {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    padding:30px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

div span {
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:#666;
    position:absolute;
    left:-1px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution. is there a way to control the size of the triangle? it's so big

Comment: Hi. You would simply change the sizes in my example to suit your needs. And obviously place a triangle graphic inside the span tag.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    margin:20px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #ededed; 
    border:#ccc solid 1px;
    position:relative;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    top:42%;
    left:-11px;
    border-right:#ccc solid 1px;
    border-top:#ccc solid 1px;
} ​
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rLZkf/26/)**